# Get database row in expandablelistview

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I would like to get the row number from a database in an expandablelistview. I intend to use it in arraylist to access the relative record. Is there any way, except from querying the cursor and iterating through all records? Here's my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

    Log.i(TAG, "groupPos = " + groupPosition + " childPos = " + childPosition);

    long packedPos = expandableListView.getExpandableListPosition(groupPosition);
    Log.i(TAG, "packedPos = " + packedPos + "grouPos = " 
    + ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(packedPos));
    Log.i(TAG, " getPackedPositionForChild = " + ExpandableListView.
            getPackedPositionForChild(groupPosition, childPosition));
    Log.i(TAG, "getPackedPositionForChild= " + ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild
            (ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForChild(groupPosition, childPosition)));
    Log.i(TAG, "flatPos= " + expandableListView.getFlatListPosition
            (ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForChild(groupPosition, childPosition)));

    Log.i(TAG, "childId= " + mCursorAdapter.getChildId(groupPosition, childPosition));

    Log.i(TAG, "combinedId= " + mCursorAdapter.getCombinedChildId(mCursorAdapter
            .getGroupId(groupPosition), mCursorAdapter.getChildId(groupPosition, childPosition)));


    Cursor c = mCursorAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    Log.i(TAG, "c.pos = " + c.getPosition());

    Cursor g = mCursorAdapter.getGroup(groupPosition);
    Log.i(TAG, "g.pos = " + g.getPosition());

    Log.i(TAG, "selPos = " + expandableListView.getSelectedPosition());
    Log.i(TAG, "selItemPos = " + expandableListView.getSelectedItemPosition());
    Log.i(TAG, "selId = " + expandableListView.getSelectedId());
    Log.i(TAG, "selItemId = " + expandableListView.getSelectedItemId());


    TextView dateTV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date_textview);
    TextView bGMeasurementTV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.measurement_textview);
    TextView timeOfDayTV = (TextView) (mCursorAdapter.getGroupView(groupPosition, 
            true, null, null)).findViewById(R.id.date_text_group);

    String date = dateTV.getText().toString();
    Float bGMeasurement = Float.valueOf(bGMeasurementTV.getText().toString());
    String timeOfDay = timeOfDayTV.getText().toString();
    Uri idUri = Uri.parse(BgContract.CONTENT_URI + "/" + id);

    Intent i = new Intent(BgExpandableListActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(DATE, date);
    i.putExtra(BGMEASUREMENT, bGMeasurement);
    i.putExtra(TIMEOFDAY, timeOfDay);
    i.putExtra(IDURI, idUri.toString());
    i.putExtra(ID, id); //that's the row number I am looking for 

    //startActivity(i);
    return super.onChildClick(parent, v, groupPosition, childPosition, id);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is given by the following code:

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
    // Get group and child position -- expandableListView is a reference to an
    // ExpandableListView widget

    int groupPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(expandableListView
            .getExpandableListPosition(position));
    int childPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(expandableListView
            .getExpandableListPosition(position));
    long childId = mCursorAdapter.getChildId(groupPos, childPos);

    //Do whatever you want here...
    return true;
}
```